# controlling an application solution with multiple multithreaded projects

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, logic, multiple-projects

from my main project I am running some other executables mainly from the current solution.

the output window shows me info on exiting threads when I suspect they shouldn't, what leads me to the question, how do I run my application child projects so I could process which is which ?

`mainApp.exe` , `sideProj1.exe` ...

in main app I do as follows :

```
public static bool LounchSideProj1Exec()
{
    /*
    here I could simply call it via Process.Start();
    or if I could somehow, execute it via thread start,
    so I could  name the thread  and then see it in the output window and other places...
    */
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo Pinf = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

    var CurMachingMatchsProcs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName.ToLower().Equals("sideproj1"));
   //check count, take first, this is a running process of SideProj1 else excute sideProj1:
   sideProj1Proc = CurMachingMatchsProcs.First();
   //       or else...

    SideProj1Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    Pinf.FileName = @"G:\...sideProj1.exe";
    sideProj1Proc.StartInfo = Pinf;


    bool okTh = false;
    ThreadStart ths = new ThreadStart(() => { okTh = sideProj1Proc.Start(); });

    Thread th = new Thread(ths);
    th.Name = "sideProj1THREAD";
    th.Start();
}
```

**what is the right approach to "Be In touch" With ..Concert Of Executed projects & main?**

Comment: _The thread '<No Name>' (0x1a78) has exited with code 0 (0x0)._

Answer (score 0):

so for the issue of recognizing which thread is which

in the constructor of main form

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "AppMainTRD";
```

according to the project name..

and another thing I did not know is that I could execute the whole solution as starting project, which will accrue only for debug purpose which is good for now.